# How to append data to same row with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is populated with data from an ajax call.
Is it possible to append the new data on the same table row as the data that is already there? The example below appends the data to a new row first. Here is a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/31c5njee/2/)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Add data</a>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable tbody').append('<td>info,</td>');
    });
});
```

Comment: $('#myTable tbody tr').append('<td>info,</td>'); that is enough

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable tbody tr:last').after('<tr><td>info,</td></tr>');
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but only after the ajax is completed and the html is on the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {


         $('a').click(function() {
               if($('#myTable > tbody > tr.dynamically-added-by-ajax').length) {//test if the html from the ajax is present on the page
                  $('#myTable > tbody > tr.dynamically-added-by-ajax').append('<td>additional info ,</td>');
               }
         });
```

if the clicked element is added through ajax you need to delegate the click event for it

```
$('#myTable').on('click','a',function() {
   //the append function 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
   $('#myTable tbody tr:first').append('<td>info,</td>');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, It will add new `td` to you table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');
    });
});
```